# one of the Collection View Not Scrolling, inside container view

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

So i have three containerViews inside the parent view, first one contains a static tableview which works fine.
Second ContainerView has a collectionView inside it which scrolls horizontally fine and didSelect & didDeselect get called as well.
Third containerView also has another collectionView in it; however, it does not scroll horizontally which is set in storyboard nor does didSelect and didDeselect gets called.

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "TimeCollectionViewCell"

class TimeCollectionViewDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    private let dataSource = TimeModel()
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.getReservationTimeIntervals().count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TimeCollectionViewCell

        // dateFormatter indicates how the string will look like
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

        // get the array of times
        let times = dataSource.getReservationTimeIntervals()

        cell.timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: times[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}





import UIKit


class DateCollectionVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!

    private var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    private let currentDate = NSDate()
    private var daysInMonth = Int()
    private let dataSource = DateCollectionViewDataSource()
    private var isSelected = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dateCollectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        dateCollectionView.delegate = self

        monthLabel.text = getMonth()
    }

    // based on current Date, just extract the Month
    func getMonth() -> String {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate as Date)
    }

    // user taps cell & check Mark appreas or disappears
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell

        // checks to see if same cell was tapped again
        if !isSelected {
            selectedCell.checkMarkImageView.alpha = 0.75
            isSelected = true
        } else {
            selectedCell.checkMarkImageView.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    // user taps a different cell and check mark disappears
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell

        selectedCell.checkMarkImageView.alpha = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: full code can be found on GitHub https://github.com/alirezatab/WFcodingChallenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view class is marked as `TimeCollectionViewCell` instead of `UIView`

[image]

Implement delegate methods and it will work.